# Displaying Progress Monitor for opening a Wizard in Eclipse Java SWT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, progress-bar, swt, jface

I was trying to add a Progress Monitor for a Wizard Dialog in Eclipse in Java using SWT, but I'm getting an unusual error with no message at all. Here is my code:

This is the class I made for displaying the progress monitor:

```
public class OpenWizardsAction implements IRunnableWithProgress{

    private WizardDialog dialog;
    private String monitorMessage;

    public OpenWizardsAction(WizardDialog dialog,String monitorMessage)
    {
        this.dialog=dialog;
        this.monitorMessage=monitorMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException
    {
        // Tell the user what you are doing
        monitor.beginTask(monitorMessage, IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);

        // Do your work
    
        if(Window.OK==dialog.open()) {}

        // You are done
        monitor.done();
    }
}
```

And this is where I call this class:

```
WizardDialog dialog;
dialog = new WizardDialog(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), new RunWizard(runSum,runTable));
try {
    IRunnableWithProgress op = new OpenWizardsAction(dialog,"Opening Run Wizard");
    new ProgressMonitorDialog(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell()).run(true, true, op);
} catch (Exception e) {
    MessageDialog.openError(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), "Unable to open Run Wizard", e.getMessage());
}
```

The `MessageDialog.openError` call shows empty message i.e. `e.getMessage() is empty`.

Is it because I'm using the same Display and Shell for both Wizard and ProgressMonitorDialog?

I also tried adding the below line in place of line 5 in the second code segment:

```
new ProgressMonitorDialog(new Shell(Display.getDefault(),SWT.NONE)).run(true, true, op);
```

Still there was error with an empty message.

Comment: What is the actual class of the Exception? Code in the `run` method of a progress monitor runs in a background thread, you can't do UI operations there.

Comment: oh okay, is there a way to do UI operations and show Progress Monitor similar to what I've tried, maybe that should be another question. Not sure about the exception type.

Comment: Do some debugging, find out what the exception class is. Do whatever  your long running work is in the progress monitor and then open the dialog when the operation is complete (when the `ProgressMonitorDialog.run` returns).